# Why did the hard drive go stealth?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I had a really weird problem with my 1 year old OS disk recently.

I was using my computer when suddenly some process took ages to complete. 
I tried to close it, but then everything stopped responding, like when something is eating all your cpu.
After waiting a bit I used the power button to restart the computer.

When it turned on again it told me to "reboot and insert a proper boot device."

I entered BIOS and discovered that it didn't see the OS HDD anymore.

- I switched the power and data cables, nothing changed.
- I have 2 other HDDs that work fine, so the MB is not the problem.
- I tried using the Windows installation disk to check for applicable disk drivers, no luck.

---

I had my father look at the disk, and he got it working with no problems at all. He connected it to his laptop with a USB-SATA adapter and played it like an external hard drive. No trouble at all.
However he told me that he couldn't open\access the Documents folder on the OS partition.

When I got it back, I had no problems either getting it to start. However there were some odd things:

- When I first started it again chckdsk wanted to inspect the disk for errors.
- Some private folders give me Access Denied regardless of what I do:

  - Documents and Settings
  - C:\ProgramData\Application Data
  - C:\ProgramData\Desktop
  - C:\ProgramData\Documents
  - C:\ProgramData\Favorites
  - C:\ProgramData\Start menu
  - C:\ProgramData\Templates
- Windows Live mail no longer works. At the first try it gave some error, and later it won't even start.
- Note the weird "ProgramData" folder. I'm using English Windows, but my father uses Norwegian. It looks to me as if his computer has moved several folders automatically.
  He did tell me that he neither could access the folders listed.

---

- What happened?
- Why did it stop working?
- Why does it work again after 'visiting' a different computer?

Comment: There is nothing obscure about the specific c:\programdata folders you listed being inaccessable using that method. go through the c:\users (whatever user) to get to that. They are like linkey things for back compatability while MS rearraged everything to make it easy LOL.  Try using Programs and features to remove and reinstall anything that isnt working it will re-link that in.  Could be you also have some issues with the specific user.  and What is the actual OS, other than "windows"?

Comment: Next you still Must run a SMART testing on the drive, before assuming all is well.  check for reallocated sectors, and watch closely for any added reallocated sectors.  Chkdsk going off is nothing, that is just because the disk was marked dirty, if you have real problems your not knowing about the Smart test would be the thing to see.